# How can I augment a globally declared class?

Tags: typescript

Fetch `Response` class has some convenient static methods:

- [`error()`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-response-error)
- [`redirect(url, status)`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-response-redirect)
- [`json(data, init)`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-response-json)

I want to safely define my own using [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) while avoiding future name collisions by using [symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) but TypeScript is giving me some trouble augmenting the globally declared `Response` class.

I can do this unsafely without symbols:

```
function _html(body?: BodyInit | null, init?: ResponseInit): Response {
  const headers = new Headers(init?.headers);
  if (!headers.has("Content-Type")) {
    headers.set("Content-Type", "text/html");
  }
  return new Response(body, { ...init, headers });
}

declare global {
  namespace Response {
    const html: typeof _html;
  }
}

Object.defineProperty(Response, "html", { value: _html });
```

I can't find any valid syntax for using a `unique symbol` as the method name though:

```
export const html = Symbol();

function _html(body?: BodyInit | null, init?: ResponseInit): Response {
  const headers = new Headers(init?.headers);
  if (!headers.has("Content-Type")) {
    headers.set("Content-Type", "text/html");
  }
  return new Response(body, { ...init, headers });
}

declare global {
  namespace Response {
    const [html]: typeof _html;
       // ^^^^^^ Type '(body?: BodyInit | null | undefined, init?: ResponseInit | undefined) => Response' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.(2488)
  }
}

Object.defineProperty(Response, html, { value: _html });
```

Comment: Without [ms/TS#38613](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36813) being addressed I don't see how this could be possible.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That shadows the built-in `Response`.